# Disable validator via ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, validation

I have a simple request scoped entity / pojo which has a Enum and a String as properties.

```
public Enum Type
{
    None,
    Email,
    Fax;
}

@ManagedBean(name = "testEntity")
@RequestScoped
public class TestEntity
{
    private Type type; //Default = None
    private String address;

    //getter and setter
}
```

This Enum has a field 'Email' which identifies a e-mail address with a related address.
In JSF I now want to enable/disable a validator of a address InputText field regarding the currently selected type in a SelectOneMenu.

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="type" value="#{testEntity.type}>
        <p:ajax event="change" update=":formId:address"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="E-mail" itemValue="Email"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fax" itemValue="Fax"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:inputText id="address" value="#{testEntity.address}">
        <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" disabled="#{testEntity.type != 'Email'}"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <!-- button to call bean method with testEntity as param -->
</h:form>
```

It is not working the **validator is never active** but the ajax call is working since I can see the change value in other fields.

Comment: This is by the way an interesting idea for OmniFaces. This is not an uncommon requirement.

Comment: Nice project, will have a look at its showcase later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's unfortunately not possible. The `<f:xxx>` tags are taghandlers (not UI components) which run during view build time, not during view render time. So if it's disabled during building of the view, it'll always be disabled until the view is recreated (e.g. by new request or a non-null navigation).

You'd need to have a "global" validator which delegates further to the desired validator based on the `type` attribute.

E.g.

```
<p:inputText ... validator="#{testEntity.validateAddress}" />
```

with

```
public void validateAddress(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    if (type == Email) {
        context.getApplication().createValidator("emailValidator").validate(context, component, value);
    }
}
```

---

**Update** [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has recently added a new [`<o:validator>`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/o/validator.html) tag which should solve exactly this problem as follows:

```
<o:validator validatorId="emailValidator" disabled="#{testEntity.type != 'Email'}"/>
```

See the showcase example [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator).

Comment: It is a shared remote Entity and I don't want any jsf in it. (annotations are in faces-config either) I don't see any other way either to search the type component in the text field validator/pass its id as a attribute or validate it in the bean submit method.

Comment: Why not call "new EmailValidator().validate(...)?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your comment? Will check the new omnifaces validator out tomorrow.

Comment: Your validator is not reuseable for other validators than the email validator. So if you'd need this for another validator, you'd basically need to create/copypaste another global validator again.

Comment: Thanks, but the OmniFaces validator is not working with my RequestScoped example. I also tested it with the Entity being a property of a session scope bean where it worked.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Use the view scope instead. See also http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=19

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is interested in how I solved it thanks to BalusC help.

Pass type component clientId to custom converter.

```
<f:attribute name="typeComponentId" value=":formId:type"/>
```

Validator:

```
public class TestEntity implements Validator
{
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException
    { 
        final String typeComponentId = (String)component.getAttributes().get("typeComponentId");

        final UIInput compType = (UIInput)context.getViewRoot().findComponent(typeComponentId);

        if(compType != null)
        {
            final Type type = (Type)compType.getValue();

            if(type == Type.Email)
                new EmailValidator().validate(context, component, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Not working inside a ui:repeat component such as p:datatable.