# OmniFaces disable o:validator

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

According to this [Disable validator via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677984/disable-validator-via-ajax) I thought I could do something like:

```
<p:inputText 
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" disabled="controller.item.type != 'M'" minimum='0.75' maximum='0.99' for="factor"/>
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" disabled="controller.item.type != 'U'" minimum="0.5" maximum="0.74" for="factor"/>
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" disabled="controller.item.type != 'N'" minimum="0.0" maximum="0.49" for="factor"/>
</p:inputText>
```

But validator messages don't reflect the correct validation. Ultimately I am just trying to guide user for input range based on what they choose in a oneSelectMenu.

full code is below

```
<h:outputLabel for="type" value="Probability" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="type" value="#{controller.item.type}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Absolutely" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="Maybe" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="U" itemLabel="Unsure" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="N" itemLabel="Not Likely" />
    <f:ajax render="@form" />                           
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="type" />


<h:outputLabel for="factor" value="Factor" />

<h:panelGroup>
<p:inputText id="factor" value="#{controller.item.factor}" size="4" rendered="#{controller.item.type == 'M' || controller.item.type == 'U' || controller.item.type == 'N' }"
required="#{controller.item.type == 'M' || controller.item.type == 'U' || controller.item.type == 'N' }" requiredMessage="Factor is required">
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" disabled="controller.item.type != 'M'" minimum='0.75' maximum='0.99' for="factor"/>
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" disabled="controller.item.type != 'U'" minimum="0.5" maximum="0.74" for="factor"/>
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" disabled="controller.item.type != 'N'" minimum="0.0" maximum="0.49" for="factor"/>

</p:inputText>

<h:outputLabel id="absolutelyFactor" value="Absolutely (1.00)"
rendered="#{controller.item.type == 'A' || empty controller.item.type}" />

<h:outputLabel id="maybeFactor" value="Maybe (0.75-0.99)"
rendered="#{controller.item.type == 'M'}" />

<h:outputLabel id="UnsureFactor" value="Unsure (0.50-0.74)"
rendered="#{controller.item.type == 'U'}" />

<h:outputLabel id="NLFactor" value="Not Likely (0.00-0.49)"
rendered="#{controller.item.type == 'N'}" />
</h:panelGroup>

<p:message for="factor" />
```

**EDIT**
per BalusC's keen eye, I didn't have real EL expressions in the disabled. This works.

```
<o:validator validatorId="javax.faces.DoubleRange" disabled="#{controller.item.type != 'M'}" minimum='0.75' maximum='0.99' message="Factor is not in range 0.75-0.99"/>
```

Comment: Is this the real code? Those values in `disabled` attribute are just plain strings, not EL expressions.

Comment: doh! probably why it didn't work!

Comment: There's other probable cause, but I'll await this testing. Note that you can simplify this into only one `<o:validator>` by using conditional operator `?:` in the minimum and maximum attributes depending on the type. Oh, the `<o:validator for>` attribute is unnecessary here. It's only applicable when you nest the validator inside a composite component tag.

Comment: @BalusC seems to work after making actual EL Expressions.  I left it using three validators. Not sure how to make just one using the ternary operator.  My Q wasn't formatted properly, you can now see the selectonemenu.  Somewhere those ranges need to be defined to programmatically use in the ?:.  Along with removing the "for" I added a "message" to each validator shown in my edit.